# Problem with file App.js ( when import new .jsx file in components foler )

Tags: reactjs

I am having problem with App.js and here it is.

Here is my App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ListEmployeeComponent from './components/ListEmployeeComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import CreateEmployeeComponent from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';    
function App() {
return (
<div>
<Router>
<div className = "container">
<HeaderComponent/>
<div className="container">
<Switch> localhost:3000/add-employee
<Route path = "/" component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
<Route path = "/employees" component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
<Route path = "/add-employee" component = {CreateEmployeeComponent}></Route>
</Switch> 
</div>
<FooterComponent />      
</div>
</Router>
</div>        
);
}
export default App;
```

As you can see, I add the code `import CreateEmployeeComponent from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';` and `<Route path = "/add-employee" component = {CreateEmployeeComponent}></Route>` to this code. When there were no those line, the code ran ok.

But there are those line, I got the error like this :

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Attempted import error: './components/CreateEmployeeComponent' does not contain a default export (imported as 'CreateEmployeeComponent').
```

I am very confusing because the path is correctly ? Am I missing something ? Could you please give me some advices with this problem ? Thank you very much.

Comment: `export default CreateEmployeeComponent` make change on CreateEmployeeComponent file

Comment: your import seems correct; make sure that your export is also correct. As the errors said, and as @DivyeshKanzariya pointed out, check that you `export default CreateEmployeeComponent` from the `CreateEmployeeComponent.jsx` file

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the above comment, you have to export the `CreatEmployeeComponent` like this in `./components/CreateEmployeeComponent`;

```
import React from 'react';
...

function CreateEmployeeComponent(props) {

    ....
    return(
        ...
    )
}

export default CreateEmployeeComponent;
```

Otherwise, if you export the component like this:

```
function CreateEmployeeComponent(props) {

    ....
    return(
        ...
    )
}

export CreateEmployeeComponent;
```

then you have to import the component like this.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ListEmployeeComponent from './components/ListEmployeeComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';    
function App() {
return (
<div>
<Router>
<div className = "container">
<HeaderComponent/>
<div className="container">
<Switch> localhost:3000/add-employee
<Route path = "/" component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
<Route path = "/employees" component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
<Route path = "/add-employee" component = {CreateEmployeeComponent}></Route>
</Switch> 
</div>
<FooterComponent />      
</div>
</Router>
</div>        
);
}
export default App;
```

*As you can see above, there are two ways to use components that I know.*